# cannot find correct xpath under shell

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am fairly new to Scrapy, so please bear with me for a moment.

I want to scrape [this page](http://cordis.europa.eu/projects/242270) for the following information

- project acronym (PROTECTRAIL)
- project short description (The Railway-Industry Partnership for Integrated Security of Rail Transport)
- project long description (Facing the problem of enhancing [...] buildings and infrastructure protection)

Using Google Scraper I have inpected these elements and determined their Xpath in the html page

- acronym: `//*[@id='recorddetails']/div/div[1]/h1`
- short description: `//*[@id='recorddetails']/div/div[1]/h2`
- long description: `//*[@id='recorddetails']/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/p/text()`

I have then tested the following Xpath queries under SHELL

- acronym: `sel.xpath("//*[@id='recorddetails']/div/div[1]/h1").extract()`
- short description: `sel.xpath("//*[@id='recorddetails']/div/div[1]/h2")`
- long description: `sel.xpath("//*[@id='recorddetails']/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/p/text()").extract()`

But shell yields no result [] for these different Xpath queries, while they seem to be properly written (no syntax error) and accurate enough.

How can I find out the proper selector with the proper Xpath so as to fetch those information?

Answer (score 1):

looking at firebug net tab, filter by XHR request, it seem that the data you are after is in a latter AJAX call to:

```
$ scrapy shell "http://cordis.europa.eu/projects/index.cfm?fuseaction=app.csa&action=read&xslt-template=projects/xsl/projectdet_en.xslt&rcn=95607"
....
>>> sel.xpath("//div[@class='projttl']/h1/text()").extract()
[u'PROTECTRAIL']
```

also, better make yourself familiar with xpath syntax rather than using those auto xpath tools

Comment: Thanks for your help ! But how do I go from the original URL to the one AJAX calls to?

Comment: do you have firebug installed? its a firefox extention, better than the chrome IMO, as said in the answer, when its open, go to Net tab and filter by XHR, you'll see the call there

Comment: ok, I just had to reload the page so as to see where the AJAX call goes. I guess I'll replace all the original URL with these ones before feeding them to the spider. Thanks for your help anyway !

Comment: I have now a follow-up question about automatically retrieveng the URL the AJAX call goes. You'll find it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753030/how-to-automatically-retrieve-url-ajax-calls-to