# Scrapy, javascript form, not crawling next page

Tags: scrapy

I am having an issue. I am using scrapy to extract data from HTML tables that are displayed after a form search. The problem is that it will not continue to crawl to the next page. I have tried multiple combinations of rules. I understand that it is not recommended to override the default parse logic in CrawlSpider. I have found many answers that fix others issues but, I have not been able to find a solution in which a form POST must occur first. I look at my code and see that it requests the `allowed_urls` then POST to `search.do` and the results are returned in HTML formatted results page and thus the parsing begins. Here is my code and I have replaced the real url with nourl.com

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
from EMD.items import EmdItem

class EmdSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "emd"
    start_urls = ["https://nourl.com/methor"]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div//div//div//span[@class="pagelinks"]/a[@href]'))),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('')), callback = 'parse_item')
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        url = "https://nourl.com/methor-app/search.do"
        payload = {"county": "ANDERSON"}
        return (FormRequest(url, formdata = payload, callback = self.parse_data))

    def parse_data(self, response):
        print response
        sel = Selector(response)
        items = sel.xpath('//td').extract()
        print items
```

I have left `allow = ('')` blank because I have tried so many combinations of it. Also in my xpath leads to this:

```
<div align="center">

<div id="bg">
    <!--

     Main Container 

    -->
    <div id="header2"></div>
    <!--

     Content 

    -->
    <div id="content">
        <!--

         Hidden/Accessible Headers 

        -->
        <h1 class="hide"></h1>
        <!--

         InstanceBeginEditable name="Content" 

        -->
        <h2></h2>
        <p align="left"></p>
        <p id="printnow" align="center"></p>
        <p align="left"></p>
        <span class="pagebanner"></span>
        <span class="pagelinks">

            [First/Prev] 

            <strong></strong>

            , 

            <a title="Go to page 2" href="/methor-app/results.jsp?d-49653-p=2"></a>

            , 

            <a title="Go to page 3" href="/methor-app/results.jsp?d-49653-p=3"></a>

             [

            <a href="/methor-app/results.jsp?d-49653-p=2"></a>

            /

            <a href="/methor-app/results.jsp?d-49653-p=7"></a>

            ]

        </span>
```

I have checked with multiple tools and my xpath is correctly pointing to the URLs to go to next page. my output in the command prompt is only grabbing data from the first page. I have seen a couple of tutorials where the code contains a yield statement but I am not sure what that does other than "tell the function that it will be used again later without loosing its data" Any ideas would be helpful. Thank you!!!

Comment: Have you examined this url to next page closely? Can you post it here? Sometimes urls contains cookie_sessions and they can be only viewed in one browser, you can see if this is the case by copy pasting the url into another browser. If the url contains some cookie, then you need some other way of extracting links, most likely crawl spider will be too limited for your purposes here. I wrote an answer to similar question here, you can check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753030/how-to-automatically-retrieve-url-ajax-calls-to/21804808#21804808 maybe it will help?

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you need to select the actual URL in your rule, not just the `<a>`node. `[...]` in XPath is used to make a condition, not select something. Try:

```
//span[@class="pagelinks"]/a/@href
```

Also a few comments:

- How did you find this HTML? Beware of tools to find XPath, as **HTML retrieved with browsers and with scrapy may be different**, because scrapy doesn't handle Javascript (which can be used to generated the page you're looking at, and also some browsers try to sanitize HTML).

  It may not be the case here, but the "javascript form" in a scrapy question spooked me. You should always check that the content of `response.body` is what you expect.
- `//div//div//div` is **exactly the same** as `//div`. The two slashes means we don't care anymore about the structure, just select *all the nodes named div* in the children of the current node. That also why here `//span[...]` might do the trick.

Comment: I did try that, however...it does not seem to help. I am pretty sure that scrapy is not handling any javascript. The form is posted and the results are in HTML. I checked scrapy's `response.body` it is the same html as I am getting when I inspect it with firefox. I dont know if it makes a difference but the links are not full-urls for example the xpath leads for 4 urls which are in `/methor-app/results.jsp?d-5555p-2` format